# can't use flash in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: firefox, flash, opera

Since I upgraded to ubuntu 13.10, my flash isn't working anymore in firefox or opera. It only works in Google Chrome as it is included in the browser. I did check that I have flash plugin for firefox and so on installed. Everthing did work before the upgrade. When I try to install from adobe's website, it doens't pick up anymore the apt installer/ software center. You have to physically to go and look for the correct program to install flash, but I don't know where to look for it or choose it. Is there a other way like in terminal or somewhere else to reinstall it? Or what can I do?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: I have tried that, but is already installed

Comment: Maybe it is a matter of enabling the shockwave plugin within Firefox.

Comment: I just tried that and installed the plugin also for firefox, but still no change

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue after upgrading. I found the removing `flashplugin-installer` first then re-installing it (as suggested by chronitis) worked:

```
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: You're better of using `purge` instead of `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that is bug or may be older version like.

download the tar file from this location and install this tar file.

http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.310.orig.tar.gz

it is updated version of the flashplugin.

Comment: Thanks, but the previous solution I got did work and it fixed my flash problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a manuall install of libflashplayer.so to make it work.
This is how I did..

Go to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ 
Download the tar.gz from the dropdown list.

```
mkdir -p ~/src/flashplayer
sudo mv ~/Download/install_flash_player_11_linux_x86_64.tar.gz ~/src/flashplayer/ (or whatever your download folder and architecture are)
cd ~/src/flashplayer/
tar zxvfp install_flash_player_11_linux_x86_64.tar.gz
mkdir -p ~/.mozilla/plugins
cp libflashplayer.so ~/.mozilla/plugins
```

Restart Firefox and see if it works..

I did a write-up here [1](http://www.mockel.se/index.php/2013/11/arrh-flashplugin-on-ubuntu-13-10-problem/)

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same problem under xubuntu 13.10 with only that line:

```
sudo aptitude -f reinstall flashplugin-installer
```

Strangely, `dpkg-reconfigure flashplugin-installer` did not do anything, seems like `adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.327.orig.tar.gz` is not downloaded at the time of the installation

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` This command need to install flash player and more usefull extensions, like video-audio codecs.

Comment: s/buntu/ubuntu/g

Comment: What this mean?